# Deploy ASP.NET Core without runtime and packages?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012, msdeploy

I'm doing build & deploy content in `Visual Studio` but this takes a lot of space (170 MB) because it contains runtime `(dnx core clr)` and all packages files.
Can I deploy `web app` to `windows server` and automatically install runtime and all packages on server for my `web app`?

Comment: .NET Native is coming, which will shrink all of them to a single executable. So wait and wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scripted it to download the runtime as you instal it.

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}"
```

Dependencies can be then be dowloaded using the `dnu restore` command based on you `project.json` file.